# Partial page return on c client and telnet

Tags: c, httprequest, telnet

I am attempting to request a webpage through my own client and the webpage returns are missing content. The same occurs when I attempt to Telnet the request for the page. I've tried with both the code and a stripped version found here (both return the same result):

http://coding.debuntu.org/c-linux-socket-programming-tcp-simple-http-client

The webpage I am requesting is the one below, easily accessible from a browser however when I attempt to access it with my own client I am missing large portions of content both in Telnet and with the Code. I have played around with buffer sizes and once this gave slightly greater results but on a second run the content was gone.

http://www.asx.com.au/asx/research/companyInfo.do?by=asxCode&asxCode=MQG

How can I make a page request and get the full page source?

Comment: I was increasing the buffer size to take in more data, whereas a content section in a webpage may be overlooked if the receiving client may ask for the next chunk of 1028 bits. If you ask for a smaller buffer chunk you are then less likely to miss content. I think that's why decreasing the buffer size worked anyways.

Comment: Use a library that's built to do HTTP requests, not this piece of junk. Try [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), for instance.

Comment: I see no obvious problems with the code. Try debugging it. First I would start with wireshark. Do you see the page arriving on the wire? If not, something must be wrong with your request. Compare the traces of your program and the browser, eventually you should be able to get the same page as the browser. If that still does not work, debug the program. Does the program retrieve any chunks of the page? Why does it stop? Maybe you are hitting the case described in comments: "Under certain conditions this will not work..."

Comment: Fair enough @duskwuff. I was getting the webpage back, except with huge chunks of the content missing. In the previous comment I made, I tried to offer an explanation at why decreasing the buffer size made an impact.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to request the page using following requestlines:

```
GET /asx/research/companyInfo.do?by=asxCode&asxCode=MQG HTTP/1.0
UserAgent: Myself
```

The result I got was:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Age: 36
Date: Wed, 30 Jan 2013 07:12:03 GMT
Content-Length: 38060
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Server: Apache
Content-Language: en
```

Including the whole page contents that the browser gets too. I guess the problem that you don't find the information you are looking for comes from the fact that the page contains dynamic (JavaScript) parts that are loading more information immediately after the page is displayed in the browser.

If you want to grab specific information from this page you have to dissect the page content analyzing the JavaScript parts and reverse engineer the interface how these parts are retrieving information.

Side note: If you can afford it (in terms of space and complexity) use a library like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) that already covers a lot of issues you have to take care of when implementing HTTP.